# how to determine the mode of child batch file from parent batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to open a batch file from another batch file in a different folder. The second batch file should appear across the screen but I want to determine the mode from the first (parent) batch file. Can this be done. So far I have done this

`start /max test.bat`

My second batch file is

```
@echo off
color 5f
echo THIS WILL SHUTDOWN YOUR COMPUTER
PAUSE
CHOICE /C 123 /M "Press 1 to shutdown, 2 to restart or press 3 to cancel shutdown."
if errorlevel 3 goto END
IF errorlevel 2 goto ONE
IF errorlevel 1 goto ZERO

goto END
:ZERO
echo this is a shutdown command
shutdown.exe /s /t 000
goto END
:ONE
echo This is a restart command
shutdown.exe /r /t 000
:END
echo this will cancel
exit
```

Comment: What does "determine the mode from the first (parent) batch file" mean?

Comment: @SiHa I want the mode on test.bat to be 200 but I want this to be determined by the initial file. can this be done?

Comment: screen size? buffer size ? colors? quick edit mode? code page? delayed expansion? command extensions? echo on/off?  Mode could mean a lot of things...

Comment: @npocmaka in this case I meant screen size

Comment: yes.But will require a C# code..

Comment: Perhaps you could just pass the "mode" by reference in starting `test.bat`?